# Q: Different behavior on different application (always repeat the previous command (by default the version - ATI))

Tags: at-command, elm327

I was poking around with a elm327 and found that according with the type of application I use some were always returning the same response from the elm327 (the last executed command, which was the ATI (the version) in my case).

If I was using an application that send straight away what I was typing (like putty, screen) then it was executing the last command.

If I was using an application that send the command all at once (an cellphone application where you have to click on "submit" or it the "enter" key) (more technicaly: Something that will fillup the read buffer) then the command got processed as expected.

Settings I used:

Speed: 9600 bauds

Databits: 8

Stop bits: 1

Parity: none

Row control: None (in fact anything seem to work)

Command terminaison: 0A (Carriage Return; confirmed by a HC-06; seem to be the default for terminal application)

Version returned by my elm327 : v1.5

Answer (score 0):

**A:** You probably have a cheap elm327 with a buggy firmware, use an application that send the command all at once (NOT putty/kitty,hyperterminal, screen). Probably something like a cellphone application, your own application, arduino serial)